# How to access the global styles.scss from static privacy / legal / conditions assets document?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7, assets

I have a static document e.g. `privacy.html` which is under:

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/src/assets/html/privacy.html
```

I also have my global (common to all components) styles under:

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/src/styles.scss
```

I access the static html file from a component like this:

```
<input type="checkbox">
  <span>
    I agree to the <a target="_blank" href="/assets/html/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>.
  </span>
...
```

Now the `privacy.html` doesn't get the styles when imported as simply as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.scss">
```

How would you cover this use-case? Note that making the `privacy.html` a component would be a complete overkill.

Comment: Are you compiling your scss to css?

Comment: I have no idea :P where do I see that? when I do `ng serve` I find no `styles.css` file anywhere. For the record, I also tried with `styles.css` and still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your problem?

Comment: @FlavioCaruso thanks for asking, not yet. The Angular 7 framework is doing this transformation implicitly but the file `privacy.html` in the assets doesn't see the resulting `styles.css` so that's my problem and OP and why the solution you drafted doesn't help me. One possibility is to duplicate the relevant css styles within the `privacy.html` and make it self contained but that's a non elegant workaround and not a long term viable solution I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile your scss to css and then link your css.

Using watch Like that

sass --watch styles.scss styles.css

Then you link the css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```